# How do I find patches in debian packages?

Tags: packaging, patch

How are the patches in debian/patches obtained?

Is this

```
diff -Nurp folder/original folder1/new
```

enough?

Answer (score 5):

This usually depends on the type of patch system which the package uses.

There are 3 types of patch systems for Debian packages:

1. Quilt (most widely used)
2. Cdbs + Simple Patchsys
3. dpatch

All patch systems store patches in debian/patches. You can use the what-patch command in package [ubuntu-dev-tools [image: Install ubuntu-dev-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-dev-tools) to find out which patch system a package is using.

Introduction of **Quilt**:

Quilt patches can be easily manipulated using the quilt command from a terminal. The quilt command is a part of package [quilt [image: Install quilt]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quilt).

[This page](http://wiki.debian.org/UsingQuilt) will help you getting along with quilt. Also check out the quilt manpage by running

```
man quilt
```

in a terminal.

Now for **cdbs** + **simple-patchsys**:

These patches are manipulated commonly by a script called `cdbs-edit-patch` in package [cdbs [image: Install cdbs]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cdbs). You can edit patches like this:

```
cdbs-edit-patch *PATCHNAME*
```

You can add new patches like this:

```
cdbs-edit-patch *NEW_PATCHNAME* *PREV_PATCHNAME*
```

Where `*PREV_PATCHNAME*` is the name of the patch after which `*NEW_PATCHNAME*` will apply.

**dpatch**:

[dpatch [image: Install dpatch]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dpatch) patches can be manipulated using the script dpatch-edit-patch in package [dpatch [image: Install dpatch]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dpatch). The usage of dpatch-edit-patch is exactly the same as cdbs-edit-patch above.

Comment: Being an Ubuntu Developer I never had to create patches manually like you said. The above ways do the work all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The section "Modify upstream files" of http://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/07/04/how-to-prepare-patches-for-debian-packages/ explains how those patches are created when the patch system in use is quilt (which is the most common case thanks to the new source format "3.0 (quilt)").